# While vs For-loop

Tags: java

Are these basically the same?

1) While

```
int i = 0, j = 0;

while (i < 10) {
    while (j < 10) {
    } j++;
} i++;
```

2) For

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    }
}
```

Still kind of new to programming and I just wanted to know. Which one would be more efficient if they are the same?

Comment: Test it first before coming here, and then you'll find one loop is infinite. -1 for not even running this code first -- I know that you can do better at asking questions than this.

Comment: As posted, the loops are not equivalent. You *could* make them equivalent, but then there would be no difference in efficiency between *these* constructs. If you were to include streams, there *might* be a performance difference (for larger ranges than 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same. 
1 is wrong, and you will stuck in the while loop since the j++ is out of the block. If you want to make 1 doing the same thing as 2, should change to:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;  
while (i < 10) {
    j = 0; 
    while (j < 10) {
        ....
        j++;
    } 
    i++;
}
```